# Dynamically adding a certain amount of list items eg.7 lis

Tags: jquery

Hey guys how can i append certain number of `<li> </li>` to a Ul.
I can certainly do this `$('#thumbsList').append('<li></li>');`

But how can i tell jquery to add say 7 list items fo eg if the number comes from a variable.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I **hope** you heard about loops).

Is that what you're looking for ?

```
for (var i=0;i<myParam;i++)
{
 $('#thumbsList').append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
}
```

Comment: oh!! i almost for about it.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[.append( function(index, html) )](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html)

```
var list = $('#thumbsList'); //cache selector
for (var i = 0; i < myParam; i++) {
    list.append(function () {
        return '<li>' + i + '</li>';
    });
}
```